# JQuery Mobile: back button on page header, but not popup header

Tags: jquery-mobile

I would like to have a back button on the page, using `data-add-back-btn="true"`. However I also want a popup on the same page, with a header, that doesn't have a back button on it. It seems that the `data-add-back-btn="true"` attribute applies to everything on the page.

I've played around with different settings here: http://jsfiddle.net/n9trV/4/ but have had no luck. Can anyone get this working?

Is there any neat way of doing this using the JQM attributes? Otherwise I will probably just delete the button manually after the page has initialised.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should report this as a bug (I feel it is so). However, to solve your problem just using markup, you can delete the

```
data-add-back-btn="true"
```

and place inside of your page header, whether it's a `<div>` or a `<header>` (better), a link like the following:

```
<a href="#" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" title="Go back">Back</a>
```

If you want to use your previous icon, in the link use this attribute instead:

```
data-icon="arrow-l"
```

So you should have something like this:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page2">   
   <header data-role="header">
      <a href="#" data-icon="back" data-rel="back" title="Go back">Back</a>
      <h1>Page 2</h1>
   </header>
   <!-- other code goes here -->
</div>
```